# Proof of greedy algorithm.

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, computer-science

Given n numbers find the way to assign them to blocks of 3 (and possible one block of 1 or 2 if n is not divisible by 3) so that sum of smallest elements from each full block is maximal.

ie.
numbers 400, 350, 300, 250, 200, 150, 100, can be divided into [400, 350, 300], [250, 200, 150], [100] with above mention sum of 450.

I know that correct approach is just to assign numbers to block in sorted order(so first block contains first, second and third largest element and so on), but i can't find a way to prove it correctness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We sort all the blocks according to the descending order of their minimal elements. We name the blocks $B_1, B_2, \dots$ in that order.

For every $i\geq 1$, let $m_i$ be the smallest element of $B_i$. Thus $m_j \geq m_i$ whenever $j \leq i$.

For any $1 \leq j \leq i$ and any element $x \in B_j$, we know that $x \geq m_j \geq m_i$.

This means that, for any $i$, there are at least $3i$ elements (i.e. all elements from $B_1$ to $B_i$) larger than (or equal to) $m_i$.

In other words, if we sort the original $n$ numbers in descending order as $x_1, x_2, \dots$, then we must have $m_i \leq x_{3i}$.

Adding everything together, we see that the sum $m_1 + m_2 + \dots$ is at most $x_3 + x_6 + \dots$.

On the other hand, this upper bound can be achieved simply with the greedy algorithm: group them as $\{x_1, x_2, x_3\}$, $\{x_4, x_5, x_6\}$, etc.